# get correct view of child in expandable list view

Tags: java, android

My expandable list view adapter implements interface for click listener on the items of child view. When I click on the button on the childview of expandable listview, I need to get the view of the child at run time. How this can be done?

I tried :

```
View view = expandableListView.getChildAt(expandableListView.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(groupposition, childpostion)));
```

My click listener provides the group position and child position:

```
public void onItemClick(int position, int gposition){
}
```

But I am not able to get the required view of the child.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some global variable/object. Then use setTag(View v) method to tag that child View, which was clicked. Later you can access that child by using getTag() method.

Comment: Can u give some examples so that i can understand well.

Comment: Lets say you have a button(or maybe some image) in your child view. Now inside getChildView method of your custom adapter you can tag your button as button.setTag(View_Name). Then implement onClickListener of that button. Inside onClick(View arg0) you can fetch the clicked view as: View v = (View)argo.getTag();